# Python, PEP-8 and multi-line dict formatting

Tags: python, pep8

I have to declare some `dict` in Python. I write such a code:

```
class MegaClass(object):
    _activation_grad_classes = \
    {
        activation.ForwardStrictRELU: activation.BackwardStrictRELU,
        activation.ForwardLog: activation.BackwardLog,
        activation.ForwardSinCos: activation.BackwardSinCos
    }
```

And get a PEP-8 error: `E122 continuation line missing indentation or outdented`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 11):

Put the opening curly brace on the assignment line:

```
_activation_grad_classes = {
    activation.ForwardStrictRELU: activation.BackwardStrictRELU,
    activation.ForwardLog: activation.BackwardLog,
    activation.ForwardSinCos: activation.BackwardSinCos
}
```

There *rarely* is a need to use `\` to escape a newline in Python; instead use `{..}`, `[..]` and `(..)` to group expressions across multiple lines.

Comment: The only time I ever use '\' is `multi_line_text='''\ ` to escape the first newline and the text in the here document lines up as it will once defined.

Comment: @dawg: indeed, that is the only place I ever use it as well, and only because that makes the first line neater.